# Show revision diff color toggle

Tags: script, posts, revisions

Sparked by [this feature request on meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/325873/216074), I created a quick user script that offers a toggle to show or hide diff colors.

Look at the following screenshot to see it in action. The upper view is how it looks with enabled diff colors (default case, matching the behavior without the extension), and the one on the bottom shows how it looks with the colors disabled:

[image: Revision diff color toggle example]

### Install and source

- **[Click to install](https://gist.github.com/poke/a065aa208e225894c3daf8408e69d448/raw/stackexchange-diff-color-toggle.user.js)**
- [Source](https://gist.github.com/poke/a065aa208e225894c3daf8408e69d448)
- Current version: 1.2.0 (2021-02-12 21:56 UTC)

### Changelog

- **1.2.0:** Update for changed UI
- **1.1.1:** Code cleanup and minor improvements
- **1.1.0:** Add functionality to review pages (suggested edits)
- **1.0.0:** Initial release

Comment: Shouldn't this work in /review/suggested-edits too?

Comment: @NathanTuggy Good idea, added those URLs in the new version.

Comment: Apparently adding the `suggested-edits` URLs was not enough. When visiting one of those pages, I still do not get the toggle to show up. That page apparently does not have the same `revisions` nodes as the other pages.

Comment: @JustinWood Oh, you’re right, I should have tested that before… It’s not only a different structure (which isn’t that big of a problem) but the content is actually rendered later using JavaScript. I’ll have to figure out how to attach to that process so I can process it after it is rendered…

Comment: Okay, it should work now! Finally got to use mutation observers for something (although that totally wasn’t necessary here ;P)!